# How to get current element of shuffled array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a div that plays random animal sounds when the user clicks it. I am trying to extract the current sound name so that I can later check if it matches the user input or not. Currently my code extracts only one value from the array of objects 'goat' and it doesn't show the animalType according to the sound mp3, how can I make so I extract the current sound animalType property that is playing?

Here is my code:

```
var sounds = [
  {
    animalType: 'horse',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Horse-neigh.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'bear',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/grizzlybear.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'goat',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Goat-noise.mp3'),
  }
]

var player = document.getElementById('player');
var enteredWord = document.getElementById('entered-word');
var counter = document.getElementById('counter-score');

shuffleAnimalSound();


  function shuffleAnimalSound() {
    player.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
      for(var i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) {
       var currentSound = sounds[i]
      }
      console.log(currentSound.animalType)
      sound['sound'].play();
    })
  }
```

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) {
       var currentSound = sounds[i]
      }`

Makes no sense, so you loop over everything to get the last item in the array?

Comment: `var sound` is the randomly selected animal. Therefore `sound.animalType` is the animal type, and `sound.sound` is the `Audio`. As @epascarello points out, that section is not necessary as  you're not looping through anything. Try `console.log(sound.animalType)` instead.

Comment: Of course, the lack of sleep is getting to me hah, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are logging the incorrect variable:

```
var sounds = [
  {
    animalType: 'horse',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Horse-neigh.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'bear',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/grizzlybear.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'goat',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Goat-noise.mp3'),
  }
]

var player = document.getElementById('player');
var enteredWord = document.getElementById('entered-word');
var counter = document.getElementById('counter-score');

shuffleAnimalSound();


  function shuffleAnimalSound() {
    player.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var sound = sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*sounds.length)];
      /* for(var i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) {
       var currentSound = sounds[i]
      }*/
      console.log(sound.animalType)
      sound['sound'].play();
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it would technically be

```
console.log(sound.sound)
```

May want to change up those var names

If you want to extract the sound GIVEN the animalType...

```js
var sounds = [
  {
    animalType: 'horse',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Horse-neigh.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'bear',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/grizzlybear.mp3')
  },
  {
    animalType: 'goat',
    sound: new Audio('../sounds/Goat-noise.mp3'),
  }
]


var results = sounds.filter(function(cv,i){
 return (cv.animalType==='goat') ? cv.sound : false;
})

console.log(results[0])
```

Comment: You're logging the `Audio` object. I think you want `sound.animalType` instead.